# How to sort a tab-separated file?

Tags: bash, csv, sorting, tabs

I'm trying to use **sort** to sort a tab-separated file like this one:

```
Fruit       Color   Origin              Category
pear        green   Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés
strawberry  red     Reggio Calabria     garden strawberry
apple       green   Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés Arkansas Black
banana      yellow  Makindye Ssabagabo  East African Highland bananas
```

by every column. This is what I ended up with (`<n>`: column number):

```
$ sort -t $'\t' -k <n>  <(tail -n+2 fruits.tsv)
```

which works for the first 2 columns but not for the 3rd and 4th column. E.g. for the 4th column I get this:

```
banana      yellow  Makindye Ssabagabo  East African Highland bananas
apple       green   Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés Arkansas Black
pear        green   Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés
strawberry  red            Reggio Calabria      garden strawberry
```

which is wrong. Besides that, the 4th line appears shifted in the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got more than one tab separating columns?

Comment: What's your locale?

Comment: @glenn jackmann: Yes

Comment: @tripleee: LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your data with every tab converted to `|`:

```
pear||green|Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés|Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés
strawberry|red||Reggio Calabria||garden strawberry
apple||green|Oviedo–Gijón–Avilés|Arkansas Black
banana||yellow|Makindye Ssabagabo|East African Highland bananas
```

As you can see there are places where two tabs separate what you think are neighbouring columns; `sort` will see a column with a blank entry there.

Solution: replace multiple tabs with a single tab before you sort.

```
tail -n+2 fruits.tsv | tr -s '\t' | sort -t $'\t' -k <n>
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18438161)).

If you'd like the output to *look* nice, pass the result through `column`:

```
… | column -t -s $'\t'
```

(this `$'\t'` will be substituted with tab character in `bash`). This however will introduce spaces instead of tabs, so the final result will be rather impossible to parse further. Use `column` only when presenting to humans.

Some pagers (like `less`) can also present your tab-separated data in a nicer way:

```
… | less -x 25
```

Comment: I have tried with single tab before and I thought it wasn't working either but I was wrong...Also the output looks nice but the file is still not easily readable. Is there any way to have multiple tabs and the sorting still works?

Comment: @coverflower I would sanitize the *data* to have single tabs and store it in this form; then I could sort in any way I need. Any time I need human-readability, I would use `column` on the *result*.

Comment: @coverflower I have added a remark about `less`.

Comment: It looks even better with less...

Answer (score 0):

With an extra step (Source:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437884/replacing-tabs-with-single-tab-in-sed][1]):

```
tr -s '\t' '\t' < fruits.tsv > fruits_single_tab.tsv

tail -n+2 fruits_single_tab.tsv | tr -s '\t' | sort -t $'\t' -k 4 | less -x 25
```

I can have multiple tabs in the file.